# Can i use the Turtlebot simulator for ROS Kinect?

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found no way to bring it up for Ros Lunar so i switched to Kinect.

Is there any way how i can use Turtlebot ?

It would be fine enough for me when i could get a model for the turtlebot and when i can move him.

I hope someone can help me !

I got struggel here :

sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot ros-kinetic-turtlebot-apps ros-kinetic-turtlebot-interactions ros-kinetic-turtlebot-simulator ros-kinetic-kobuki-ftdi ros-kinetic-rocon-remocon ros-kinetic-rocon-qt-library ros-kinetic-ar-track-alvar-msgs Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-rocon-remocon E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-rocon-qt-library

My Solution until now is that i dont install those packages. Until now Simulation works fine,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271628/can-i-use-the-turtlebot-simulator-for-ros-kinect-?/) by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2017-09-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, packages are only available in a ROS distribution if the maintainers release it into that particular distro.  You can find out if the package you want is released into the distro you want by going to https://wiki.ros.org, and typing the name of the package of interest into the search bar.  Doing that for the packages you are having trouble with leads me to here: http://wiki.ros.org/rocon_remocon .  You can see along the top bar that that package has only been released for inidigo, not kinetic, which is why you can't find those packages.  Your options at this point are either to switch to indigo, or to ask the maintainers of those packages to release them into kinetic.  Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [clalancette](https://answers.ros.org/users/30031/clalancette/) with karma: 256 on 2017-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0